# How accurately can 使い be translated as "angel"?

Tags: translation, words, meaning, religion

On jisho.org, 使い is translated with words such as "errand", and the same holds true on translate.google.com.  Neither site is offering "angel" as a suggestion.  Yet in Matthew 1:20, the phrase:

> ・・・主の使いが夢に現れて言った。

is found in English as:

> . . . an angel of the Lord appeared to him in a dream and said . . .

Does it mean "angel" or not?  Is the Japanese saying something slightly different than "God no angel"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

使い doesn't mean angel in all contexts, but *does* mean "messenger/bearer/...". In particular, the usual word for "angel" is [天使]{てんし} or [天]{てん}の使い = "messenger from heaven". Here you don't have 天, but 主 "Lord/God".

As snailplane points out in the comments, the phrase "Angel of the Lord" should appear frequently. Wikipedia [writes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_of_the_Lord):

> The **Angel of the Lord** (or the **Angel of God**) is one of many terms in the Hebrew Bible (also: Old Testament) used for an angel. The Biblical name for angel, מלאך *malak*, which translates simply as "messenger," obtained the further signification of "angel" only through the addition of God's name, as ("angel of the Lord," or "angel of God", Zech. 12:8).

The same in Japanese. 使い translates simply as "messenger" and only obtains the further signification of "angel" only through the addition of God's name (or through the honorific prefix [御]{み}, as in ssb's answer). In that sense, the Japanese 主の使い seems to be faithful to the original Hebrew.

Comment: English [*angel*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=angel&allowed_in_frame=0) comes from Greek [ἄγγελος](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%84%CE%B3%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (*angelos*) "messenger", which was used to translate the Hebrew [מלאך](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_of_the_Lord) (*mal'akh*) "messenger".  So it seems that etymologically speaking it's messengers all around.

Comment: @snailplane So you're saying that the Greek/Hebrew version, whichever was the original text for this translation, most likely had "messenger of the Lord"?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be correct.  I edited references into my first comment :-)

Answer (score 10):

使い refers to someone sent to a specific place to fulfill a certain objective for someone else. In this purely semantic sense 主の使い would be an angel just because that's the role it is describing.

[御{み}使い](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BE%A1%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84) seems to be the "right" (or at least most direct) translation for angels in a Christian/biblical sense:

> 御使い（みつかい、 ヘブライ語: מלאך‎、ギリシア語: ἄγγελος）は、使者を意味する語であり、キリスト教で主の使いである

Notice that the definition above uses the term 主の使い itself. It appears that it is also a standard way to phrase things in a Christian context.

[天使{てんし}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E4%BD%BF) applies more broadly to the concept of an angel in a faith-agnostic sort of way. 使い on its own also seems to have roots in Japanese traditional religions as a term for beings/animals acting as representatives of gods.

Comment: I don't know why, but somehow I don't expect 御使い to be used in a translation of the bible. Maybe because it somewhat conflicts with the plain style I expect (i.e. plain style of verbs and no honorifics).

Comment: I throw out all expectations when it comes to biblical translations. Says plain as day, though: "御使い（みつかい、 ヘブライ語: מלאך‎、ギリシア語: ἄγγελος）は、使者を意味する語であり、キリスト教で主の使いである"

Comment: I guess I was wrong: Both the [modern](http://ja.wikisource.org/wiki/%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E7%A6%8F%E9%9F%B3%E6%9B%B8%28%E5%8F%A3%E8%AA%9E%E8%A8%B3%29#9:26) and [literary](http://ja.wikisource.org/wiki/%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AB%E5%82%B3%E7%A6%8F%E9%9F%B3%E6%9B%B8%28%E6%96%87%E8%AA%9E%E8%A8%B3%29#9:26) translations on Wikisource use 御使.

Comment: @Earthling:  What part don't you expect, the 御 or the 使い?  In the case of the former, 御 is used on many things related to God in Japanese Christianity:  御父【おん・ちち】 (the Father), 御子【み・こ】 (the Son), 御霊【み・たま】 (the Spirit), [御使]{み・つ}い  (angels, messenger), 御言葉【み・こと・ば】 (God's word / the scriptures), etc...

Comment: @istrasci I didn't expect the 御, but I've never read a Japanese bible, so I guess I'm not acquainted with "bible speak". I guess it makes for better recitation, when the 御 is already added into the text.