# Which is more natural: イエス様の救う恵み or 救うイエス様の恵み?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I'm trying to translate "Jesus's saving grace".  Translating directly from English, the phrase that comes to mind is:

> イエス様の救っている恵み

But I get the feeling that maybe it's more natural and articulate to put the verb first and the noun modifier second:

> 救っているイエス様の恵み

In English, this sort of ordering would amount to "saving Jesus's grace", which is not what's intended, but maybe it's more natural and people would understand what it really means.

So I almost asked this question to see which of those two would be more natural, but now I'm also starting to think that maybe instead of using 救っている, I should use 救う.  Is this so?  What's the most natural, articulate way to say this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Christian who worked at a Japanese church, I can say that `イエス様の救う恵み` and `救うイエス様の恵み` are both fine, although the latter is somewhat ambiguous in parsing, i.e., it could be parsed as either

> - 救う(イエス様の恵み)　→　Jesus' grace that saves.
>     OR
> - (救うイエス様)の恵み　→　The grace of Jesus, who saves.

To disambiguate it, you could add in a その

> - 救う**その**イエス様の恵み

Either way, the phrase beginning with 救う sounds more refined/formal to my ear.  And of course, if you're saying this in a more familiar setting (like to other Christians), you can leave off 様 completely.

And not to dump on @Tim's answer, but I have never heard any Japanese Christian use `神の加護`.  Sounds way too dictionary and impersonal.

Comment: If this is what the priest will say in church giving a sermon then I expect this is the answer the OP is looking for but what do they use in the Bible, if that book contains the expression? (I suspect 加護 is more formal/written and was carefully chosen by a translator rather than a Japanese preacher talking to his flock.)

Comment: @Tim:  I only find it in the Bible a handful of times (you can search it [here](http://www.bible.or.jp/read/vers_search.html)), but in these passages it only means "protection", not "grace" or "saving".  Although if you're not a Christian, the distinction between these words is probably not so clear-cut.

Comment: I had a Christian upbringing but it is only occasions like this I think about the varied meanings of words like grace, redeem, charity etc.

Answer (score 3):

After some research about this topic, I've found that "**(神の)救いの恵み**" is very frequently used by Japanese Christians. So this seems to be the exact phrase you need.

- [旧約新約聖書講解―神の救いの恵みを学ぶための](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4863250142)
- [救いの恵みと祝福](http://www.dct3.net/index.php?%E6%95%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E6%81%B5%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A8%E7%A5%9D%E7%A6%8F)
- [救いの恵みに今応答しよう](http://www.mission.or.jp/weekly/2013/%E6%95%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E6%81%B5%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%8A%E5%BF%9C%E7%AD%94%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86.html)
- [神の救いの恵み](http://nozomich.com/contents/category04/post_105.php)
- [亀戸教会 - 牧師より](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/kameido-church/church/bokushi.html)

  > 主 **イエスの救いの恵み** に応答する第一歩は、礼拝に参加すること、祈ること、聖書を読むことです。礼拝は祈りです。キリストの御名を通して、あなたの祈りが神さまに聞かれています。

And looks like "saving grace" is used by some theologians as a strictly defined technical term, as an antonym of "common grace." ([English WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_grace) and [Japanese WP](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC%E6%81%A9%E5%AF%B5)). In that case, "救いの恩寵" or "救済的恩寵" is the corresponding term of "saving grace". But I don't know whether this term is widely recognized by ordinary Japanese Christians.

And as for the difference between 恵み and 恩寵【おんちょう】, Japanese Wikipedia says that the choice of words depends on the communions.

> 「神の恵み」は日本聖書協会の口語訳聖書・新共同訳聖書、他にも新改訳聖書などで一般的な表記であるが、正教会では恩寵（おんちょう）が一般的表記である。カトリック教会では、かつては聖寵（せいちょう）と訳され、例えば伝統的な祈祷文「アヴェ・マリア」の文語訳（天使祝詞）では「めでたし聖寵･･･」と唱えられていた。いまは「恩寵」と表記される例も稀にあるが、カトリック教会のカテキズムや公式文書等では「恵み」「神の恵み」「恩恵」と表記されている。また、プロテスタントにも「恩寵」の語彙を用いるものがある。

And you may also have to change the word choice depending on the intended audience. I can say 恵み is recognized by almost all native speakers (not to say the precise definition is understood). I, as a non-Christian, feel 恩寵 is very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You're a little mixed up about the English grammar and its equivalence in Japanese; "saving" is not present progressive, but a participle adjective.

イエス様の救い would be enough I think, though you could make it "fancier" if you like.

Answer (score 2):

For an expression like this (a kind of 専門用語）there is likely to be a commonly used phrase you won't be able to come up with from scratch, and the majority of people have to look it up.

I found this on the internet:

> saving grace of God | 神の加護

I expect you could use it for Jesus too.

Comment: But in majority of people for theology 専門語, you should include most Japanese people, so this might be dictionary-accurate but is it meaningful to regular people or obscure?

Comment: I don't understand your comment but "saving grace" is an expression associated with the bible/God/Jesus which has become a colloquialism in secular society for a "redeeming quality" while the individual words, saving and grace have taken on new meanings: Such an expression is not easily translated and, just like in any field, I find it most effective to keep to the accepted expressions to avoid confusion.

Comment: (I think I now understand your comment): In western/christian country an expression like this will be readily accepted, even by non-chistians because it so well know it has become a colloquialism.  In a non-christian society (or group of people not familiar with any field under discussion) I think it is best to find out the accepted translation and be ready to provide an explanation:  I am not sure many people in western societies really understand "Jesus's saving grace", they let it go without a 2nd thought because they all ready understand enough of what is being said to get by.

Comment: 「神様/仏様の(御)加護」はネイティブなら誰でも知っている、比較的平易な日本語だと思います。多分「[恩寵【おんちょう】](http://goo.gl/OWILJx)」の方が正確かつ専門用語的だと思いますが、この辺りになると知らない人もいそうです。

Comment: Yeah, that's part of what I was going at. I'm a Christian in Japan but *never* use 基督教専門語 if at all possible. But if naruto is saying this is well-understood, then it might work. But considering it's also used for 仏様, it might not have the right meaning...

Comment: Well, 「加護」 is [very widely used](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=の加護) and will work fine in most cases, but strictly speaking, it may be more like *protection* rather than *grace*.

Comment: Another question raised by the OP presented a similar challenge: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14299/how-accurately-can-使い-be-translated-as-angel  The translators appear to look for words that will capture the correct meaning rather  than literally translate - possibly the expression is deliberately borrowed from bhudism because it will be recognised.  (I am sure I have read about similar practices carried out by early missionaries in Japan).

Comment: @Tim I think that one's actually pretty opposite of this. Having looked around a bit, I don't think Christians use 加護 as a translation for grace. In that case, お使い is a very literal translation of the Greek word *angelos* which means "messenger." It's rather that the English transliterated word angel has added specific ideas not present in the Biblical text.

Comment: In terms of the borrowing from Buddhism thing, there are two things I can think of off the top of my head. One is that Francis Xavier was originally saying something that got him mistaken for 日蓮. The other is the 隠れクリスチャン who came up with a muddled Lord's prayer and have their very own somewhat syncretized ideas.

Comment: @virmaior : It is a while since I read it but you might find the following interesting: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRXKM2tGGnY